# Loading Output of Apache Pig into Python

Tags: python, apache-pig

I would like the process the (small) output of a set of Pig jobs in Python.  Is there a way to interact with Pig's output without writing my own parse-from-string methods?

Answer (score 0):

Check out python embedding:

http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/embedding.html

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/cont.html#embed-python